# FTP files matching user-specified time range using Windows batch line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I am trying to create a simple batch file(s) that a user can click and it will prompt the user for a begin date and end date (format `yyyymmdd`) and will then ftp the files with a matching file name.

The file names are in the format `yyyymmdd.3P.site.name_address.csv`. So if the user entered `20160101` and `20160103`, then it would ftp 3 files (the 3 that start with `20160101`, `20160102`, and `20160103`).

Since the date format in the filename is INT friendly, my thinking was to parse out the first 8 characters from the file names, and download any that are between the user input.

My problem is that I don't know how to store the 2 user inputs and compare to the parsed out file names. Here is my code at present:

test.bat

```
ftp -i -s:test.ftp
```

test.ftp

```
open ftp.somesite.com
username
password
lcd %UserProfile%\Desktop\ftptest
cd folderwithfiles
get 20160518.3P.site.name_address.csv
bye
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run `ftp` twice. First to get the listing. Then you parse the listing, find the files your want, generate new FTP script with one `get` command per each matched file and run the `ftp` again.

Something like this:

```
@echo off

set HOSTNAME=example.com
set USERNAME=user
set PASSWORD=pass
set SOURCE=/path
set /P FROM=Date from:
set /P TO=Date to:

echo open %HOSTNAME%> ls.txt
echo %USERNAME%>> ls.txt
echo %PASSWORD%>> ls.txt
echo cd %SOURCE%>> ls.txt
echo ls . list.txt>> ls.txt
echo bye>> ls.txt

ftp -s:ls.txt

del ls.txt

echo open %HOSTNAME%> get.txt
echo %USERNAME%>> get.txt
echo %PASSWORD%>> get.txt
echo cd %SOURCE%>> get.txt

rem Some servers will prefix all entries for "ls ." with "./"
rem For such servers, use the syntax with delims=/ to separate the filename from the prefix.
rem FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%i in (list.txt) do call :process %%j
rem But some servers do not add the prefix, for those this will do:
FOR /F %%i in (list.txt) do call :process %%i

echo bye>> get.txt

del list.txt

ftp -s:get.txt

del ls.txt

:process

set NAME=%1
set TIME=%NAME:~0,8%

if "%TIME%" geq "%FROM%" if "%TIME%" leq "%TO%" echo get %NAME%>>get.txt

exit /b
```

---

Or, if you can rely on file timestamps, you can use FTP client capable of selecting files based on a time range.

For example with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/), the script can be as simple as:

```
set /P FROM=Date from:
set /P TO=Date to:

winscp.com /ini=nul /command ^
    "open ftp://user:pass@example.com/" ^
    "get ""/path/*>=%FROM%<=%TO% 23:59:59""" ^
    "exit"
```

The dates have to be entered in a format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

References:

- [Automating file transfers from FTP server](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation);
- [File masks with time constraints](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#size_time).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: I've added an alternative solution using WinSCP.

Comment: Thanks for the great tips. I don't want to rely on file timestamps and am trying to keep this to batch file only so the users don't have to install an FTP client. 

When using your solution above, something is not working. It is successfully creating the list.txt with all the file names, but the get.txt doesn't have any file names in it, so I am guessing there is an issue with the loop. I am trying to figure it out...

Comment: What does the `list.txt` look like?

Comment: here is the first several lines: 20160328.3P.site.name_address.csv
20160512.3P.site.name_address.csv
20160506.3P.site.name_address.csv
20160211.3P.site.name_address.csv
20160305.3P.site.name_address.csv
20160127.3P.site.name_address.csv
20160408.3P.site.name_address.csv
20160510.3P.site.name_address.csv
20160218.3P.site.name_address.csv
20160427.3P.site.name_address.csv
20160224.3P.site.name_address.csv
20160131.3P.site.name_address.csv

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! I also sucessfully combined it with athoer tool I wrote that merges all the csv's together into one file. Thank you.